# Python pandas to mimic excel pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

Coming from Excel and very willing to change to Pandas I am reading Wes McKinneys book... having lots of fun with it... But also trying out some of my own stuff...

Let's say we have a data frame that can be read through the following csv file:

```
city,inhabitants,city_type,county
city a,9483,city,diggersville
city b,2628,city,diggersville
city c,5206,city,diggersville
city d,5206,city,diggersville
city e,839,village,crazytown
city f,3574,city,crazytown
city g,35,village,crazytown
city h,8214,city,downsend
city i,4278,city,downsend
```

so my code would be something like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.txt')
```

I want to calculate the following two things per county and city_type combination:

1. Sum of inhabitants
2. Count of # of cities/villages

and I want to have these besides each other as columns in my resulting dataframe.

I know how to calculate the two individual facts:

```
data.groupby(['city_type','county']).sum()
data.groupby(['city_type','county']).city.count()
```

but as mentioned above I would like to have these combined in one resulting dataframe (like a pivottable in Excel):

```
                         my_count   my_sum
city_type  county      
city       crazytown       1          3574
           diggersville    4         22523 
           downsend        2         12492
village    crazytown       2           874
```

any help is appreciated here on how to accomplish, since I really want to show of my colleagues that Python is soooooo easy :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [pass a dict to the `agg` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns). The keys are column names, and each value is the corresponding function you wish to use to aggregate the column:

```
In [98]: data.groupby(['city_type','county']).agg(
             {'city': 'count', 'inhabitants': 'sum'})
Out[98]: 
                        inhabitants  city
city_type county                         
city      crazytown            3574     1
          diggersville        22523     4
          downsend            12492     2
village   crazytown             874     2
```

Comment: This is why I love StackOverflow.... within 4 minutes someone is able to answer my question... Thanks unutbu!!!

Comment: And for those also reading the book... this is discussed on p.262 and further.... I am still at the data wrangling chapter where some of the summing is shown and wanted to try something more real life for me..

Comment: Note that pandas has function `pivot_table` for spreadsheet like pivot tables as documented at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html Though I (as a non Excel person) find @unutbu's solution easier to comprehend.